# Tools to create a browser game host bot (Headless/WebRTC)

Tags: phantomjs, webrtc, p2p, headless, slimerjs

I'm planning to create a bot that manages a room of a HTML5/WebRTC browser game which should run 24/7 on my headless server.

It won't be there to participate in the game but only to host a room and extend it with some useful features. But before I even think about implementing those extra features I need to get the basics done.

So I wanted to know which tools I could use to first only access the game like any normal user would, create a room and be a stable host without needing a graphical browser.

I saw in some older post that there are tools like phantom.js but it doesn't seem to support WebRTC.

Thank you in advance

Comment: just because the game is browser-based doesn't mean your bot has to, you can connect directly to the websocket with any sort of network stack.

Comment: Use c++ WebRTC Native or https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc on server side